# Could not connect to the message store javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTH] Username and password not accepted

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Hi there I am trying to 
Download attachments in e-mail messages using JavaMail

Reference from this site: [Download attachments in e-mail messages using JavaMail](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/download-attachments-in-e-mail-messages-using-javamail)

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Could not connect to the message store javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTH] Username and password not accepted.
```

Below is the code:

```
 public class EmailAttachmentReceiver {
 private String saveDirectory;

 /**
  * Sets the directory where attached files will be stored.
  * @param dir absolute path of the directory
  */

 public void setSaveDirectory(String dir) {
    this.saveDirectory = dir;
 }

 /**
 * Downloads new messages and saves attachments to disk if any.
 * @param host
 * @param port
 * @param userName
 * @param password
 */
 public void downloadEmailAttachments(String host, String port,
        String userName, String password) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    // server setting
    properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.pop3.port", port);

    // SSL setting
    properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port",
            String.valueOf(port));

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    try {
        // connects to the message store
        Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
        store.connect(userName, password);

        // opens the inbox folder
        Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        // fetches new messages from server
        Message[] arrayMessages = folderInbox.getMessages();

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayMessages.length; i++) {
            Message message = arrayMessages[i];
            Address[] fromAddress = message.getFrom();
            String from = fromAddress[0].toString();
            String subject = message.getSubject();
            String sentDate = message.getSentDate().toString();

            String contentType = message.getContentType();
            String messageContent = "";

            // store attachment file name, separated by comma
            String attachFiles = "";

            if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
                // content may contain attachments
                Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                    MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) 

        multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                    if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                        // this part is attachment
                        String fileName = part.getFileName();
                        attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
                        part.saveFile(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);
                    } else {
                        // this part may be the message content
                        messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
                    }
                }

                if (attachFiles.length() > 1) {
                    attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
                }
            } else if (contentType.contains("text/plain")
                    || contentType.contains("text/html")) {
                Object content = message.getContent();
                if (content != null) {
                    messageContent = content.toString();
                }
            }

            // print out details of each message
            System.out.println("Message #" + (i + 1) + ":");
            System.out.println("\t From: " + from);
            System.out.println("\t Subject: " + subject);
            System.out.println("\t Sent Date: " + sentDate);
            System.out.println("\t Message: " + messageContent);
            System.out.println("\t Attachments: " + attachFiles);
        }

        // disconnect
        folderInbox.close(false);
        store.close();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
        System.out.println("No provider for pop3.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not connect to the message store");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

   /**
   * Runs this program with Gmail POP3 server
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String host = "pop.gmail.com";
    String port = "995";
    String userName = "your_email";
    String password = "your_password";

    String saveDirectory = "E:/Attachment";

    EmailAttachmentReceiver receiver = new EmailAttachmentReceiver();
    receiver.setSaveDirectory(saveDirectory);
    receiver.downloadEmailAttachments(host, port, userName, password);

 }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your user/password is correct? Have you tried getting those messages using desktop email client such as Thunderbird?

Answer (score 0):

First, correct these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Clearly the server thinks you've supplied the wrong username and password.  If you turn on [session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug), you may find more clues as to what the server thinks is wrong.  You may also need to set the "mail.debug.auth" property to "true" to see the full authentication protocol exchange.

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.packaging.dbconnection.Database;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.search.FromTerm;
import javax.mail.search.SearchTerm;

/**
 * This program demonstrates how to download e-mail messages and save
 * attachments into files on disk.
 *
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
public class EmailAttachmentReceiver {
    private String saveDirectory;

/*vxcvxcv*/

    /**
     * Sets the directory where attached files will be stored.
     * @param dir absolute path of the directory
     */
    public void setSaveDirectory(String dir) {
        this.saveDirectory = dir;
    }

    /**
     * Downloads new messages and saves attachments to disk if any.
     * @param host
     * @param port
     * @param userName
     * @param password
     */
    public void downloadEmailAttachments(String host, String port,
            String userName, String password) {

        PreparedStatement pst;
        ResultSet rs;

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

        //session reading

        // server setting
      //  properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
     //   properties.put("mail.pop3.port", port);

        // SSL setting
    //    properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class",
    //            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    //    properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    //    properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port",
   //             String.valueOf(port));



        try {
            // connects to the message store
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
            Store store = session.getStore();
            //store.connect(userName, password);

            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "yourmail@gmail.com", "yourpass");
            //Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
           // inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);



            // opens the inbox folder
            Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            // fetches new messages from server
            SearchTerm sender = new FromTerm(new InternetAddress("xyz@gmail.com"));
         //   Message[] messages = inbox.search(sender);
            Message[] arrayMessages = folderInbox.search(sender);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayMessages.length; i++) {
                Message message = arrayMessages[i];
                Address[] fromAddress = message.getFrom();
                String from = fromAddress[0].toString();
                String subject = message.getSubject();
                String sentDate = message.getSentDate().toString();

                String contentType = message.getContentType();
                String messageContent = "";

                // store attachment file name, separated by comma
                String attachFiles = "";

                if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
                    // content may contain attachments
                    Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                    int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                    for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                        MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                        if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                            // this part is attachment
                            String fileName = part.getFileName();
                            attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
                            part.saveFile(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);
                        } else {
                            // this part may be the message content
                            messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (attachFiles.length() > 1) {
                        attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
                    }
                } else if (contentType.contains("text/plain")
                        || contentType.contains("text/html")) {
                    Object content = message.getContent();
                    if (content != null) {
                        messageContent = content.toString();

                    }
                }

                // print out details of each message
                System.out.println("Message " + (i + 1) + ":");
                System.out.println("\t From: " + from);
                System.out.println("\t Subject: " + subject);
                System.out.println("\t Recieved Date: " + sentDate);
                System.out.println("\t Message: " + messageContent);
                System.out.println("\t Attachments: " + attachFiles);

                try{
                String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname";
                String user="root";
                String pass="";

                Class.forName(driver);
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
                pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into applications() VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
                pst.setString(1,i+"1"); 
                pst.setString(2,from);
                pst.setString(3,subject);
                pst.setString(4,sentDate);
                pst.setString(5,attachFiles);


                int j = pst.executeUpdate();
                if(con!=null){
                System.out.println("connected");
                 }
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(EmailAttachmentReceiver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(EmailAttachmentReceiver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

            // disconnect
            folderInbox.close(false);
            store.close();

        } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
            System.out.println("No provider for pop3.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect to the message store");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs this program with Gmail POP3 server
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = "pop.gmail.com";
        String port = "995";
        String userName = "yourmail@gmail.com";
        String password = "yourpass";

        String saveDirectory = "D:/Attachment";

        EmailAttachmentReceiver receiver = new EmailAttachmentReceiver();
        receiver.setSaveDirectory(saveDirectory);
        receiver.downloadEmailAttachments(host, port, userName, password);

    }
}
```

In above code I have given downloading attachment code and with this I have also saved that emails in database in D:/Attachment folder.So hope you will find what you want.

Comment: Please don't use snippets for languages that are not Javascript.

Comment: I've locked the post for now to bring it your attention that 1. Don't use snippets for Java code (What Mark has said before). 2. Don't roll back meaningful edits.